# Scope of a Local variable in a cfm page?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

The following is on a `test.cfm` page:

```
<cfscript>
        Local.myString = "Hello";
</cfscript>
```

What is the scope of `myString`? Will it be visible in other parts of the `cfm` page or just between the `<cfscript>`tags where it was defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Outside of a function, that assigment sets a variable `variables.local.myString`, and the scoping rules of the variables scope are well documented: [About scopes: variables](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/About+scopes#Aboutscopes-variablesScope). From the docs:

> The default scope for variables of any type that are created with the
>   cfset and cfparam tags. A Variables scope variable is available only
>   on the page on which it is created and any included pages (see also
>   the Caller scope).Variables scope variables created in a CFC are
>   available only to the component and its functions, and not to the page
>   that instantiates the component or calls its functions.

The local scope is likewise document on that page, btw.

Consulting the docs is always a good place to *start* when having questions about the language.

Comment: So I could as well leave the `Local.` out and just use `myString = "Hello";` to create the variable `variables.myString`?

Comment: While technically the "variables" scope is optional, it is better to specify it explicitly.  Primarily for greater precision. When you omit the scope, you leave it up to CF to figure out which scope contains the specified variable name (see "Evaluating unscoped variables").  That is often undesirable. It can even lead to unexpected results in cases where there's a scope conflict.  Plus, explicitly scoping all variables just makes the code more intuitive IMO.