# What are the pros and cons to explicitly scoping a variable inside a function?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml, cfc

I read that in CF you should always scope the variables because if you don't provide an explicit scope CF will have to search through the scopes until it finds the variable. Is this really the case? If so, `test2()` would be the more efficient way of writing the function?

```
<cfscript>
    function test() {
        var result = 5;
        result = 42;
        return result;  
    }

    function test2() {
        var result = 5;
        Local.result = 42;
        return Local.result;    
    }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Should I bake a chocolate cake or a vanilla cake. Which is best? Ummmm... this isn't an opinion site. It's a site to ask questions that can be answered without regard to opinion.

Comment: @EvikJames the argument I read was that if you explicitly scope the variable the code will be more efficient since CF wouldn't need to search through the scopes. Hence the question has a technical answer that doesn't depend on opinion.

Comment: "Best practice" is always an opinion. maybe you should reword the question to instead ask which one is "fastest", or which one uses the least processing, or which one... i dont know, some other criteria.

Comment: See the comment by Leigh: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31336993/480894

Comment: Always scope. There's never a good reason to not scope.

Comment: (Edit) *RE: See the comment by Leigh* My comment was about precision (ie accuracy), NOT efficiency. While explicit scoping probably is slightly more efficient, it is doubtful the differences would be significant. Increased accuracy and readability are the more compelling reasons to scope.

Answer (score 4):

With the the introduction of the local scope, using the var keyword just tells CF to that the vared stuff belongs in the local scope.  Both examples accomplish the same thing.

I would recommend against mixing the two.

Comment: ooops!  Thank you for catching that.

Comment: But wouldn't it be more efficient to explicitly mention the scope?

Comment: @Roland sort of, but `local` and `arguments` scope are the first scopes CF will look for, so it's not too big of a deal.

Comment: @Roland - Forget about efficiency. In most cases differences are negligible. The reason to scope explicitly is to ensure accuracy and readability. Imagine you forgot to var scope `result` and the omitted the "Local." prefix. The function variables would leak into the variables scope, creating the potential for some nasty threading issues. Scoping explicitly avoids those kinds of mistakes. Can you skip scoping in this case? Yes. Should you? No.

Comment: @Leigh from the CF documentation [You cannot access the function-local scope for user-defined functions (UDFs) that you define using CFScript as a structure.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7fdf.html)

Comment: @Leigh (regarding my last comment) That is what is written in the documentation, yet from my experiments using "local." to access function local variables works fine. Confusing.

Comment: @Leigh please have a look at the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517428/coldfusion-local-scope-outside-of-a-function

Comment: @Roland - As noted on your other thread, it is just a poor description in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

(what I do) is var a LOCAL variable as a structure to contain all my variables needed inside the function, I have modified test2() to show this. We do this to ensure backwards compatibility with CF8. As we still deal with CF8 and CF9 servers.

```
<cfscript>
    function test() {
        var result = 5;
        result = 42;
        return result;  
    }

    function test2() {
        var local = {};
        local.otherthing = 'hello';
        local.result = 5;

        Local.result = 42;
        return Local.result;    
    }
</cfscript>
```