# Coldfusion local scope outside of a function?

Tags: coldfusion, scope, coldfusion-9

What exactly is the local scope defined outside of a function?

Consider the following code:

```
<cfscript>

    local.madVar2 = "Local scope variable";

    function madness() {
        var madVar = "madness variable";
        madVar2 = "madness two variable";

        writeOutput("local: <BR>");
        writeDump(local);
        writeOutput("========================================= <BR>");

        writeOutput("local.madVar2: <BR>");     
        writeDump(local.madVar2);
        writeOutput("<BR>========================================= <BR>");

        writeOutput("madVar2: <BR>");       
        writeDump(madVar2);
        writeOutput("<BR>========================================= <BR>");

        writeOutput("variables.madVar2: <BR>");     
        writeDump(variables.madVar2);
        writeOutput("<BR>========================================= <BR>");
    }

</cfscript>
```

[image]

Changing the madVar2 assignment by adding the `var` keyword, like this:

```
function madness() {
    var madVar = "madness variable";
    var madVar2 = "madness two variable";
```

Will yield this output:

[image: Image 2]

Comment: I can't be bothered wading through your obtuse repro case (hint: always use meaningful variable names, even in a repro case. Perhaps *especially* in a repro case as you want other people to read it), but there's no `local` scope outside a function so when you set `local.madVar2`, you're actually setting `variables.local.madVar2`. Is that being borne out by what you're seeing? Care to make a more lucid repro?

Comment: The ColdFusion way of implicitly assigning a variable in a (.) dot notation automatically to a struct is what to look for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Local` scope is only defined within functions and should not be used outside of it.

Variables defined outside the functions, default to the `variables` scope.

```
//that way
myVar = 0;
//will be the same as
variables.myVar = 0;
```

When you refer to `local.madVar2` variable, which was initialized outside the function you're essentially referring to the `local.madVar2` in the `variables` scope i.e the variable `madVar2` is stored inside a struct named `local` which is stored in the `variables` scope.

So essentially, with the proper scoping in place your code is treated as:

```
writeOutput("variables.local.madVar2: <BR>");     
writeDump(variables.local.madVar2);
```

Try dumping the `variables` scope just after defining the variables inside the function as:

```
var madVar = "madness variable";
madVar2 = "madness two variable";
writeDump(variables);
.....
```

You will see how the variables fall into scopes.

[image]